# How famo.us is parsing the surface properties?

Tags: javascript, css, famo.us

We have something like this:

```
properties: {
    backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 8) + ", 100%, 50%)",
    color: "black",
    lineHeight: window.innerHeight / 2 + 'px',
    textAlign: 'center'
}
```

How is famo.us parsing this object and inserting it as in-line style in the html?

How can we make some of this properties live-update such as other famo.us components?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OptionsManager in 'core' and then check out some of the basic objects like "Engine" that use it. OptionsManager emits 'change' events when "set(key, value)" is called, so you can set handlers on it and then check the 'id' field to get the thing that changed. There's an example in "Engine" looking for changes to 'fspCap' that you can use as a model. You can grab the new value from the event's 'value' field and live-update your view/component/widget.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the doc here

http://famo.us/docs/0.2.0/core/Surface

You can use `setProperties (properties)` to change it based on events (look for `Events`).

`famo.us` is just parsing everything at the same level, no nested. Also `textAlign` will be `text-align` in css.

Answer (score 0):

HP is correct if you are looking to do a direct value swap but I think you're attempting to animate so you should check out Transitionable:

https://famo.us/docs/transitions/Transitionable

https://github.com/Famous/guides/blob/master/dev/2014-04-09-animations.md